Problem with tiff file render in sequencer blender 4.1.1
I have a problem with .tiff image in Blender 4.1.1 sequencer. In Blender 4.02 the image retains its transparency.

But in Blender 4.1 the image lost all transparency. Did something change in this version or is this a bug?

